# Filter tables contain all value in another table

Tags: sql, django

i have 2 tables Product and user and each table have list of permissions i need to list to the user all product such that user have all the product permissions

check the code representation:

Product Model:

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name="Permissions")
```

and this is the user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, SoftDeletableModel):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name="Permissions")
```

lets say we have the following data:

user1 permissions A1,A2,C1,C2,C3

user2 permissions **A1**,A2,**B1**,B2,**C1**,C2,C3

product has permissions A1,***B1***,C1

user1 can not see the product "does not have B1 permission"

user2 can see the product

i tried the following:

```
Products.objects.filter(permission__in=user.permission.values("id"))
```

also tried this sql query:

```
Select * from products p 
Inner join productspermession pp
On p.id = pp.product_id
Inner join userpermessions up on pp.permession_id = up.permession_id
where up.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by check what Products that the **user can not access** and ***exclude*** product_ids from the Product filtering query

- Define new Model to represent the product-permission relation "i could not directly access the ManyToMany Model"

this is the new Model representation:

```
class ProductPermission(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", related_name="product_permission", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(
        DisclosureCenter, related_name="product_permission", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class Product(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, through="ProductPermission")
```

and in the filter part i do the following

```
excluded_products = ProductPermission.objects.filter(~Q(disclosure_center__in=user.permissions.values("id"))).all()
        

excluded_product_ids = [excluded_product.product_id for excluded_product in excluded_products]
products = Product.filter(is_removed=False).exclude(id__in= excluded_product_ids)
```

Comment: @NixonSparrow  
this is what i have done to solve the issue